# What or who is the "hauler"? [long-hauler]

Tags: word-meaning

[**This article**](https://www.yahoo.com/gma/slap-face-families-covid-19-030443232.html) has this line, saying,

> "**For the long haulers living with symptoms of COVID-19** for months on end, this virus is terrifying. Trump doesn’t care, and he still doesn’t get what families are going through," Kocher said in a statement.

Which definition is it according to [**this dictionary**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hauling)?

Thank you.

Comment: https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/long-hauler

Comment: The article would be a lot clearer if it hyphenated the term: _long-hauler_.

Comment: @gidds - And even then, given the existing term *long-haul trucker* in the U.S. lexicon, it's...less than ideal. (Though it may quickly grow in use to the point where there's no confusion.) I first read the quote above as relating to long-haul truckers who were living with symptoms of Covid-19 (a frightening prospect, if they were still truckin').

Comment: @T.J.Crowder why is that less than ideal? It comes from the same meaning of "long haul". I'm not sure most people would even get the meaning of it in this context if it weren't popularly used for truckers.

Comment: @Kat - Because of the confusion I noted in my comment.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's based on the expression "long haul".

See https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/long%20haul

> Definition of long haul
> 1: a long distance
> 2: a considerable period of time
> especially : LONG RUN

So it means people who have had symptoms for a long time. The sentence you quoted actually defines the term right after using it.

Comment: It is not the symptoms of the disease. It is the symptoms that occur after the infectious period is over.

Comment: And it should be correctly written with a hyphen: long-haulers

Comment: @user253751 - Why?

Comment: @Justin otherwise "long" is "obviously" an adjective which modifies the noun "haulers".

Comment: also 'to be in <something> for the long haul' is a common idiom

Answer (score 4):

This means people who have symptoms that last after the initial infectious period is finished.

It is a new expression that has been applied to people who experience ongoing symptoms.

For example, Chris Cuomo on CNN.

As explained in this BBC article:

[Long Covid](https://www.bbc.com/news/health-54296223)

**The origin of the idea is long-haul truck drivers or plane routes**. That is where they got it.